# Problemas ao enviar form em modal bootstrap

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, modal

Ola, estou enviando um form que esta em uma modal dentro de uma pagina, porem o modal simplesmente não envia, ele esta dentro uma pagina que é um retorno de um ajax (uma pesquisa no caso), não sei se isso influencia.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="finalizarMonitoramento{{$m->ID_CD_INTERNACAO}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="{{url('monitoramento/finalizaMonitoramento')}}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" value="{{$m->ID_CD_MONITORAMENTO}}" id="id_mot" name="id_mot">
           @method('PUT')
           @csrf
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="enviar">
        </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

essa é a modal, quando eu envio simplesmente não acontece nada. Alguma dica?

Essa é a rota:

```
Route::put('/finalizaMonitoramento','MonitoramentoController@finalizaMonitoramento');
```

Comment: Testou se a `url` e o token estão gerando corretamente? E a rota do `form`, com ela está?

Comment: Estão sendo gerados sim, a rota do form esta correta, o fato é que simplesmente não acontece nada quando eu envio o form.

Comment: Você pode adicionar sua rota na pergunta?

Comment: Ja adicionei, verifique se existe algum erro por gentileza

Comment: Só mais uma dúvida, você usa algum prefixo de nome de rota?

Comment: sim 'monitoramento', o problema não esta na rota, o problema é que o form não é enviado, não ocorre erro nenhum.

Comment: Você pode tentar isso https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686089/form-submit-button-not-working-in-bootstrap-modal-window pra tirar sua dúvida, infelizmente não terei tempo de reproduzir o erro pra tentar te ajudar

Comment: Qual é a possibilidade ter algum JS com ´preventDefault´ no submit desse form? Pois pelo que entendi o formulário não está sendo é submetido, correto?

Comment: Nenhuma possibilidade, oq eu percebi quando inspecionei o elemento é que o form abre e fecha sem nada dentro, os botoes ficam para fora

Comment: O que tem dentro do teu Controller?

Comment: Veja na aba network das ferramentas de dev do navegador, confirme que há o envio do pacote no submit do form. Se não houver, o contexto da duvida muda. Se houver, já veja qual é o response do pacote para sabermos o erro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uma alternativa a isto seria utilizar o Laravel Collective ( https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html ), pois, imagino que o problema como já foi mencionado nos comentários seja o Token.

> PS: O laravel collective precisa ser instalado conforme pode ser visto
>   [neste link](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html#installation).

**Exemplo de como ficaria o Form:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="finalizarMonitoramento{{$m->ID_CD_INTERNACAO}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    {!! Form::open(['url' => 'monitoramento/finalizaMonitoramento', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
     {{Form::hidden('_method','PUT')}}
     {{Form::hidden('id_mot', $m->ID_CD_MONITORAMENTO, 'id' => 'id_mot')}}
      {{Form::submit('enviar', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lembrando que o `{{Form::hidden('_method','PUT')}}` foi inserido para mostrar ao envio que esta requisição é do tipo PUT.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Aparentemente o seu campo ID Internação está ficando de fora do FORM não sei se isto pode estar impactando na funcionalidade também.